# Combine text from nodes with <br> in the middle using XPath

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

I have the following peace of HTML:

```
<ul class="clearfix">
<li class="li-class-name">
    <div class="head"><a href="url" title=""><img src="scr" alt="alt"></a>
        <div class="div-class-name"></div>
        <div class="another-div-class-name">
            <a href="url" title="">Name1<br>Surname1</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
<li class="li-class-name">
    <div class="head"><a href="url" title=""><img src="scr" alt="alt"></a>
        <div class="div-class-name"></div>
        <div class="another-div-class-name">
            <a href="url" title="">Name2<br>Surname2</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

I want to get pairs of Name Surname using XPath

```
//div[@class="another-div-class-name"]/a/text()
```

if I use this approach I got all the values splitted by comma, e.g: [Name1, Surname1, Name2, Surname2 ..]

```
concat(//div[@class="another-div-class-name"]/a/text()[1], ' ',  //div[@class="another-div-class-name"]/a/text()[2])
```

if I use this approach I got only the first pair, e.g: [Name1 Surname1]

However if I try

```
//div[@class="another-div-class-name"]/a/text()[1]
```

or

```
//div[@class="another-div-class-name"]/a/text()[2]
```

I got all the list of all names or surnames respectively.
Please advice how to get all names and surnames paired correctly [Name1 Surname1, Name2 Surname2 ..]

Comment: Can you update the tags  for which you are using xpath like java selenium or something else

Comment: Sure, I've already updated

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
for div in response.xpath("//div[@class="another-div-class-name"]"):
    raw_html_of_anchor = div.xpath("a").extract_first()
    surname = raw_html_of_anchor.split("<br>")[-1]
```

Comment: Thank you, but it is not XPath

Comment: @Ostap Why use xpath when CSS selector is going to work for you

Comment: @Ostap I have edited answer and added XPATH instead of CSS Selector